# Is $Z(f)=\{(t^q,t^p)|t\in K\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

$K$ is an algebraically closed field. $f(x,y)=x^p-y^q,p,q\in\mathbb{N^+}$, $f(x,y)\in K[x,y]$. Let $Z(f)=\{(x,y)\mid f(x,y)=0\}$. Is $Z(f)=\{(t^q,t^p)\mid t\in K\}$?

Comment: What have you tried? (Hint: think about roots of unity.)

Comment: @KReiser, I have tried $\mathbb{C}$, I can't find counter-example.

Comment: Do you mean $f(x, y)=y^p-x^q$?

Comment: @RobertShore,Yes!

Comment: Try $f(x, y)=x^2-y$.  What is $Z(f)$?

Comment: @RobertShore Is K $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Or just use $\Bbb A$, the algebraic closure of the rationals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Close but not quite.

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field and let $f\in K[x,y]$ be given by $f(x,y)=x^p-y^q$, where $p,q$ are positive integers.

Let $Z(f)=\{(x,y)\in K{\,\mid\,}f(x,y)=0\}$.

Clearly we have $\{(t^q,t^p){\,\mid\,}t\in K\}\subseteq Z(f)$.

To see that the inclusion can be proper, let $K$ be such that $\text{char}(K)\ne 2$ and let $p=q=2$.

Then 
$$\{(t^q,t^p){\,\mid\,}t\in K\}
=
\{(t^2,t^2){\,\mid\,}t\in K\}
=
\{(x,y)\in K{\,\mid\,}y=x\}
$$
whereas 
$$
Z(f)
=
\{(x,y)\in K{\,\mid\,}x^2-y^2=0\}
=
\{(x,y)\in K{\,\mid\,}y=\pm x\}
$$
For the general case, a correct version is as follows . . .

**Claim:**$\;Z(f)=\{(t^q,ut^p){\,\mid\,}u,t\in K\;\text{and}\;u^q=1\}$.

**Proof:**

Let $S=\{(t^q,ut^p){\,\mid\,}u,t\in K\;\text{and}\;u^q=1\}$.

By direct substitution we get the inclusion $S\subseteq Z(f)$.

For the reverse inclusion let $(x,y)\in Z(f)$.

If $x=0$, then $y=0$ so $(x,y)=(0,0)$ which is in $S$ using for example, $u=1,t=0$.

Next suppose $x\ne 0$.

Let $t\in K$ be such that $t^q=x$.

\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&
x^p=y^q
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
(t^q)^p=y^q
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
(t^p)^q=y^q
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\left(\frac{y}{t^p}\right)^q=1
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
y=ut^p\;\text{where}\;u^q=1
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
(x,y)\in S
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
which completes the proof.

Comment: Thank you for wonderful answer!